# Python Version issue with re

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I'm having a slight issue with developing a function.

The issue is with the below function.

```
def clean_file(filename, file_lines):
    file_lines = re.sub(CRYPTO_RE, subst, file_lines, re.DOTALL)
    file_lines = re.sub(REMOVE_RE, subst, file_lines, re.DOTALL)
    file_lines = re.sub(BANNER_RE, subst, file_lines, re.DOTALL)
    return get_hostname_from_file(filename, file_lines)
```

I'm developing on a 2.7 system but it will eventually run on a 2.6 system. I can not upgrade the 2.6 system as it is used for other things.

On 2.6 you just do re.DOTALL, but on the 2.7 system you have to include the flags=re.DOTALL to make it work.

I could downgrade my python version to match the production system but I wanted to approach this programmatically and solve an issue by coding. Granted downgraded would be the more practical answer.

Is there a way I can do an python version check before running the function?

Comment: [`re.sub` on Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/re.html#re.sub) doesn't take `flags` at all, you would be passing `re.DOTALL` as `count`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile the regex first and pass the flags to `re.compile`.  The object returned will have a `sub` method that should behave appropriately (as if the flag was passed in python2.7).  This behaves the same on python2.7 and python2.6 IIRC:

```
CRYPTO_RE = re.compile(..., flags=re.DOTALL)
...  # Other regex's compiled here too.

def clean_file(filename, file_lines):
    file_lines = CRYPTO_RE.sub(subst, file_lines)
    ...
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that something like

assert sys.version_info == (2,6)

Should work...  But I only run 3.x